# Relational Database Logic

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to php / mysql programming and I'm having a hard time figuring out the logic for a relational database that I'm trying to build. Here's the problem:

1. I have different leaders who will be in charge of a store anytime between 9am and 9pm.
2. A customer who has visited the store can rate their experience on a scale of 1 to 5.

I'm building a site that will allow me to store the shifts that a leader worked as seen below.

[image: screen shot of site]

When I hit submit, the site would take the data leaderName:"George",  shiftTimeArray: 11am, 1pm, 6pm (from the example in the picture) and the shiftDate and send them to an SQL database.

Later, I want to be able to get the average score for a person by sending a query to mysql, retrieving all of the scores that that leader received and averaging them together. I know the code to build the forms and to perform the search. However, I'm having a hard time coming up with the logic for the tables that will relate the data. Currently, I have a mysql table called responses that contains the following fields,

```
leader_id
shift_date // contains the date that the leader worked
shift_time // contains the time that the leader worked
visit_date // contains the date that the survey/score was given
visit_time // contains the time that the survey/score was given
score // contains the actual score of the survey (1-5)
```

I enter the shifts that the leader works at the beginning of the week and then enter the survey scores in as they come in during the week.

**So Here's the Question:** What mysql tables and fields should I create to relate this data so that I can query a leader's name and get the average score from all of their surveys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want tables like:

```
Leader (leader_id, name, etc)  
Shift (leader_id, shift_date, shift_time)
SurveyResult (visit_date, visit_time, score)
```

Note: omitted the surrogate primary keys for Shift and SurveyResult that I would probably include.

To query you join shifts and surveys group on leader and taking the average then jon that back to leader for a name.

The query might be something like (but I haven;t actually built it in MySQL to verify syntax)

```
SELECT name
      ,AverageScore
  FROM Leader a
       INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT leader_id
                         , AVG(score) AverageScore
                      FROM Shift
                           INNER JOIN
                           SurveyResult ON shift_date = visit_date
                                       AND shift_time = visit_time --depends on how you are recording time what this really needs to be
                     GROUP BY leader ID
        ) b ON a.leader_id = b.leader_id
```

Comment: Much better solution then mine. +1

Comment: @Milanzor. Not necessarily better, just more typically relational. Mine may be overkill for OPs needs. The one table solution has to duplicate leader and shift info for for each survey so it would have to somehow look up that info when a new survey was inserted, and that would become problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following structure:

**leaders**

- id
- name

**leaders_timetabke** (can be multiple per leader)

- id,
- leader_id
- shift_datetime (I assume it stores date and hour here, minutes and seconds are always 0

**survey_scores**

- id,
- visit_datetime
- score

> ```
> SELECT l.id, l.name, AVG(s.score) FROM leaders l
> INNER JOIN leaders_timetable lt ON lt.leader_id = l.id
> INNER JOIN survey_scores s ON lt.shift_datetime=DATE_FORMAT('Y-m-d H:00:00', s.visit_datetime)
> GROUP BY l.id
> ```

DATE_FORMAT here helps to cut hours and minutes from visit_datetime so that it could be matched against shift_datetime. This is MYSQL function, so if you use something else you'll need to use different function

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a 'leader' who has 5 survey rows with scores 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

if you select all surveys from this leader, sum the survey scores and divide them by 5 (the total amount of surveys that this leader has). You will have the average, in this case 3.

(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 5 = 3

You wouldn't need to create any more tables or fields, you have what you need.